# What logging framework is better to use in F# code

Tags: logging, f#

I need to add logging to my F# project.
For C# code we used: Log4net or NLog (possible two of the most popular logging frameworks for .Net).

**What is the best choice to use in F# code?**
I mean, is there any specific logging framework written for usage in F# code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The Logary library

https://github.com/logary/logary

I'm the author of Logary, which supports logging, metrics and distributed tracing for .Net Core.

Targets include: TextWriter, Console, LiterateConsole, Debugger, GCP Pub/Sub, GCP BigQuery, GCP Stackdriver, Jaeger, TCP (Shipper), UDP (Shipper), ZeroMQ (Shipper) Elasticsearch, Graphite/statsd, elmah.io, Aliyun, Azure ApplicationInsights, Mixpanel (commercial), OpsGenie (commercial), Server-sent-events (web push).

Further, you can expose a HTTP server for Proemetheus to scrape with Logary.Prometheus.

It also has a [Dash service](https://github.com/logary/logary/tree/master/src/services/dash) that supports real-time push of logs to your web browser.

Further, Logary Rutta is a sidecar container implementation or stand-alone log router for the cloud-native era.

Logary JS is a logging and metrics library for JavaScript that can ship into Logary Rutta on the server side, from where you can then furthr the logs to any of the available targets.

Logary Facade is an Apache 2-licensed facade you can copy-n-paste into all your C# and F# libraries and get high-quality console logging with.

Logary is written in F# for F# primarily.

```
Install-Package Logary
```

[docs here](https://logary.tech)

All of the above is free to use for non-commercial purposes. You can see the different [licenses](https://github.com/logary/logary/blob/master/LICENSE.md#logary-licencing) here.

Comment: Also, since this answer was written, it is important to note that Logary is no longer open source for those of us using a Microsoft "web stack", which is most of us.

Comment: @BenCollins This is lie; it's open source but the license for those using a MSFT web stack is a commercial one. It will always be open source.

Comment: @Henrik I don't mean you any disrespect, and I'm not attacking Logary, but if a library requires a commercial license for a category of users, then it seems to me that it's not open source by definition (at least for those users).

Comment: Open source is not the same as free open source. The source code is freely available and open to modification; it's just not allowed to be used in all circumstances. Otherwise, you'd say GNU v3 is also not open source, because it's not allowed to be used in the circumstance of commercial software — which is an equally absurd statement, don't you think?

Comment: The GPL doesn’t prohibit commercial use; it has conditions for redistribution.  Strictly speaking, Logary no longer meets the OSI definition of Open Source, so I don’t think I’m being absurd here.

Comment: Yes it does; if you change the code and reuse it, you have to open source your software under GPL; Logary is strictly more open than that, so I don't see what you're on about.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, they're the same for F#, i.e. there's nothing F# specific about them (whether good or bad). Aside from configuration, usage is pretty much the same for all logging libraries.

What you might want to add is printf-enabled logging, so instead of `logger.DebugFormat("Hello {0}", "world")` or `logger.Debug(sprintf "Hello %s" "world")` you can just do `logger.Debugf "Hello %s" "world"`. Use [type extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) and [kprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340484.aspx) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this can be used as solution to prepare my own logger, based on Log4Net with F# similar syntax

Comment: I often use `kprintf` to make a set of functions like you suggest, but I make them post to a `MailboxProcessor` that writes asynchronously to whatever underlying log framework I happen to be using - which may just be writing to the console in different colors for a simple command-line utility.

Comment: i asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277902/printf-style-logging-for-f feel free to elaborate :)

Answer (score 2):

I did code something like this (using verbosal syntax):

```
#light "off"
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

let inline (|?) (a: 'a option) b = if a.IsSome      then a.Value else b; // coalesce operator
  type T() = class
        static member private printLog(par) =
           match ( par) with
                | msg, Some m, Some p, Some l  -> (
                    let pl = Array.head  (Array.rev( string(p).Split([|'\\';'/'|]))) in
                    printfn "at %s(%s: line %d) %s" m pl l msg
                    )
                | msg, _,_,_ -> printfn "at ?? %s" msg
        static member LOG(msg: string, ?a:obj,
                          [<CallerMemberName>] ?memberName: string,
                          [<CallerFilePath>] ?path: string,
                          [<CallerLineNumber>] ?line: int) = match a with
                    | Some a -> (match a with
                          | :? int as i -> T.printLog((sprintf "%s %d" msg i), memberName, path,line)
                          | :? float as f -> T.printLog((sprintf "%s %f" msg f), memberName, path,line)
                          | _ -> T.printLog((sprintf "%s %A" msg a), memberName, path,line)
                                    )
                    | None -> T.printLog(msg, memberName, path,line)
          static member EXIT(?msg:string, [<CallerMemberName>] ?memberName: string,
                          [<CallerFilePath>] ?path: string,
                          [<CallerLineNumber>] ?line: int) =
                  printf "Exiting ... ";
                  T.printLog((msg |? "Giving up!"), memberName, path,line);
                  exit 1
   end
```

usage:

```
"text pushed in" |> T.LOG;
T.LOG "just text at line ";
T.LOG ("just text at line in par");
T.LOG ("string ", "text i got");
T.LOG ("int ", 1);
T.LOG ("tuple ", (1,2));
let  msg  = Some "existing optional value" in 
printfn """ (msg |? "this is default value\")  --->  %A""" (msg |? "d
T.EXIT( "after all test done no TODO new extentions");
```

produces:

```
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 49) text pushed in
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 52) just text at line
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 53) just text at line in par
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 54) string  "text i got"
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 55) int  1
at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 56) tuple  (1, 2)
'(msg |? "this is default value\")  --->  "existing optional value"
Exiting ... at testit(TautoLogics.fs: line 63) after all test done
```

just simple and eazy to use for me.