# printf style logging for f#

Tags: f#

How do i setup a printf-style logger for f# using logging library similar to log4net. 
i have Log.Debug, Info, Warn, etc. functions that are similar to DebugFormat or InfoFormat in log4net. i tried to setup type extensions for my Log class that i could call in printf style like Log.Debugf "%s" "foo". my generic log function looks like this:

```
let log format = Printf.kprintf (sprintf "%s") format
```

i am having trouble with the extension function signature to log to my Debug function...
i tried using Debugf format and Debug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with log4net, but assuming you're logging to a MessageBox (like the pros do), you can do the following:

```
let log format = Printf.kprintf (fun msg -> System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg)) format
```

In this case, since `Show` takes a string, it can be shortened to:

```
let log format = Printf.kprintf System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show format
```

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you, i danced around this for a while and finally gave up (uncharacteristically* :) )

Answer (score 5):

you mean something like this ?

```
open System

type SomeLogger() = 
    member this.Error(format : string, [<ParamArray>]args : obj[] ) = ()
    member this.Info(format : string, [<ParamArray>]args : obj[] ) = ()


module Extensions = 
    type SomeLogger with
        member this.FInfo format = Printf.ksprintf (this.Info) format
        member this.FError format = Printf.ksprintf (this.Error) format

open Extensions

let l = new SomeLogger()
l.FInfo "%d%s" 10 "123"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard logging subsystem that defined in System.Diagnostic namespace.
You shall be sure that your logging enviromnet correctly initialized. For example something like this (part of example in  C#) but it easy is linked with f# code.

```
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
try {
    TextWriterTraceListener infoTextLogger = new AlignedTextWriterTraceListener(@"c:\temp\log.log");
    infoTextLogger.Filter = new EventTypeFilter(SourceLevels.All);
    infoTextLogger.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime | TraceOptions.ProcessId | TraceOptions.ThreadId;
    Trace.Listeners.Add(infoTextLogger);
    TextWriterTraceListener consoleWriter = new AlignedTextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
    consoleWriter.Filter = new EventTypeFilter(SourceLevels.Information);
    Trace.Listeners.Add(consoleWriter);
} catch (Exception exp) {
    throw exp;
}
AlignedTextWriterTraceListener.TraceSourceNameLength = SOURCE_NAME_FIELD_LENGTH;
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Trace.TraceInformation("Logging subsystem has been initiated");
```

so in f#

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
module ClientConsole =
    let Run _ =
      Trace.TraceInformation("Client started");
```

For more convenient you can use another trace listener that definded by third party programmer.
For example lool at : [AlignedTextWriterTraceListener](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/37457/%22)