# How do I create an F# function with a printf style logging argument?

Tags: f#, printf

I'm trying to create a framework to do some processing of files and data. The one area I'm struggling with is how to provide a logging function to the framework, allowing the framework to report messages without having any knowledge of the logging in use.

```
let testLogger (source:seq<'a>) logger =
    logger "Testing..."
    let length = source |> Seq.length
    logger "Got a length of %d" length


let logger format = Printf.kprintf (printfn "%A: %s" System.DateTime.Now) format
testLogger [1; 2; 3] logger
```

Ideally I want this code to work, but I can't work out how to pass the logger function in.

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277902/printf-style-logging-for-f

Comment: I've seen that one, but it doesn't help me as I don't want the framework to know about log4net

Comment: Check out the first answer, it has nothing to do with log4net.

Comment: I voted to close the question thinking it was a duplicate - but after reading your comment, I understood that it's not (sorry about that). You want to pass the logger function as an argument!

Comment: Exactly - I want to pass the logger function as an argument!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass functions like `printf` as parameters to other functions and then use them *with multiple different arguments*. The problem is that `printf` is a generic function of type `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a`. The actual type substituted for the type parameter `'a` is some function type that is different each time you use `printf` (e.g. `'a == string -> unit` for `"%s"` etc).

In F#, you cannot have parameter of a function that is itself a generic function. The generic function will have to be some global function, but you can parameterize it by the function that actually does something with the string. This is essentially what `kprintf` does, but you can name your function better:

```
let logPrintf logger format = 
    Printf.kprintf logger format
```

An example of function parameterized by the logger would be:

```
let testLogger (source:seq<'a>) logger =
    logPrintf logger "Testing..."
    let length = source |> Seq.length
    logPrintf logger "Got a length of %d" length


let logger = printfn "%A: %s" System.DateTime.Now
testLogger [1; 2; 3] logger
```

Answer (score 17):

As Tomas points out, functions in F# can't require polymorphic arguments.  In this case, I think that Tomas's approach is quite nice, since you probably only need to be able to pass around a `string -> unit` function which is used for logging.

However, if you really do want to pass around the equivalent of a polymorphic function, one workaround is to create a simple type with a single generic method, and pass an instance of that type:

```
type ILogger = abstract Log : Printf.StringFormat<'a,unit> -> 'a

let testLogger (source:seq<'a>) (logger:ILogger) = 
    logger.Log "Testing..."
    let length = source |> Seq.length        
    logger.Log "Got a length of %d" length

let logger = { 
    new ILogger with member __.Log format = 
        Printf.kprintf (printfn "%A: %s" System.DateTime.Now) format }
```

To make this work more nicely with type inference, you could define a module with a simple helper function:

```
module Log =
    let logWith (logger : ILogger) = logger.Log

let testLogger2 (source:seq<'a>) logger =
    Log.logWith logger "Testing..."
    let length = source |> Seq.length        
    Log.logWith logger "Got a length of %d" length
```

This end result looks a lot like Tomas's solution, but gives you a bit more flexibility in how you define your logger, which may or may not actually be useful to you in this case.

Comment: +1 I quite like your first approach as you can avoid global functions.

Comment: Nice approach. I've marked Tomas as the correct answer, but I do like this approach, which I will probably use