# How to pass a printf-style function to another function in F#

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'd like to make a function in F# that accepts a printf-style function as an argument, and uses that argument to output data. Usage would be something like the following:

```
OutputStuff printfn
```

My first attempt was to let the compiler figure it all out for me:

```
let OutputStuff output =
    output "Header"
    output "Data: %d" 42
```

That fails because it decides that `output` is a function taking `string` and returning `unit`, so the second call fails.

Next I tried declaring `output` to have the same signature as `printfn`:

```
let OutputStuff (output : Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a) =
    output "Header"
    output "Data: %d" 42
```

This fails because the compiler decides that the real type of `output` is `Printf.TextWriterFormat<string> -> unit`, so again the second call fails. It also generates warning FS0064 indicating that the first call to `output` causes the code to be less generic than the type annotations, which is the crux of the issue here.

Last, I tried declaring the output function as a separate type abbreviation:

```
type OutputMe<'a> = Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a
let OutputStuff (output : OutputMe<'a>) =
    output "Header"
    output "Data: %d" 42
```

This fails with the same results as the previous attempt.

How do I convince the compiler to not specialize the type of `output` and leave it as `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a`?

Comment: Do you really need to pass the printf-like function itself? If you have some function you want to use which takes a `string` and you want to call it with the formatted string, just use `Printf.ksprintf` with your function.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569909/how-do-i-create-an-f-function-with-a-printf-style-logging-argument

Comment: You might also find this useful -- at the bottom of this file ([Pervasive.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Pervasive.fs)) there are some functions I wrote which take an arbitrary format string and which use `Printf.ksprintf` under the hood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you say `(output : Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)`, that means "**there is** some `'a` for which output takes a `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>` to an `'a`".  Instead, what you want to say is "**for all** `'a` output can take a `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>` and return a `'a`.

This is a bit ugly to express in F#, but the way to do it is with a type with a generic method:

```
type IPrinter =
    abstract Print : Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a

let OutputStuff (output : IPrinter) =
    output.Print "Header"
    output.Print "Data: %d" 42

OutputStuff { new IPrinter with member this.Print(s) = printfn s }
```

Comment: It sounds like F#'s context of generics (the a' and b' stuff) has different interpretations depending on the context (generic method vs. generic function), which is strange coming from C# and C++. Thanks for explaining the difference.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer by kvb is a great explanation of the problem - why is it difficult to pass `printf` like functions to other functions as parameter. While kvb gives a workaround that makes this possible, I think it is probably not very practical (because the use of interfaces makes it a bit complex).

So, if you want to parameterize your output, I think it is easier to take `System.IO.TextWriter` as an argument and then use `printf` like function that prints the output to the specified `TextWriter`:

```
let OutputStuff printer =
  Printf.fprintfn printer "Hi there!"
  Printf.fprintfn printer "The answer is: %d" 42

OutputStuff System.Console.Out
```

This way, you can still print to different outputs using the `printf` style formatting strings, but the code looks a lot simpler (alternatively, you could use `Printf.kprintf` and specify a printing function that takes `string` instead of using `TextWriter`).

If you want to print to an in-memory string, that's easy too:

```
let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()
OutputStuff (new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
sb.ToString()
```

In general, `TextWriter` is a standard .NET abstraction for specifying printing output, so it is probably a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I agree that this is probably more practical than the IPrinter method suggested by kvb. It was hard to decide which to accept but I went with kvb's becuase the usage inside OutputStuff is the most similar to what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `inline` feature of FSharp you can pre-configure the `Printf.ksprintf` function with a "work" function and thereby have a final function that accepts a format string together with its peculiar required parameters similar to `printf` or `sprintf`. The work function, which accepts that resulting `string`, can presumably do whatever it wants such as in the case of this logging example which prints the `string` to the `console`:

```
let logger = fun (msg:string) -> System.Console.WriteLine msg
let inline log msg = Printf.ksprintf logger msg
```

Usage examples:

```
open System
open System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

log "Hello %s, how is your %s" name Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Today)

log "132 + 6451 = %d" (132+6451)

...
```