# F# custom debug print operation

Tags: f#, printf

I would like to build a custom printing function which I use to determine what to print for a debug logger.

The function I am looking for is something like:

```
let debugLog severity ... = 
   if severity < logLevel then
       printfn ...
   // otherwise just ignore
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to fill in the ... I would also like to avoid passing a string directly as a second parameter, I would really like my function to behave like an extended printfn.

Comment: This question seems to have an answer that could be modified to do what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569909/how-do-i-create-an-f-function-with-a-printf-style-logging-argument .  However, if you want your function to work with all the magic that printf does, it will be difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`kprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340484.aspx) function.

```
let maxLevel = 3

let log severityLevel str = 
    if severityLevel < maxLevel then
        printfn "%s" str
        // or you can add more formatting
        // printfn "Level: %i -> %s" severityLevel str

let logf sevLevel str = Printf.kprintf (log sevLevel) str

logf 1 "Message: %i" 1 // prints 'Message: 1'
logf 4 "Message: %i" 2 // doesn't print
logf 2 "Message: %s %i" "this is test" 3 // prints Message: this is test 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of would be to use `fprintf` with `stdout` when you do want to print, and `TextWriter.Null` when you don't.

```
let logLevel = 3

let debugLog severity format =
    let out =
        if severity < logLevel then
            stdout
        else
            System.IO.TextWriter.Null
    fprintfn out format

debugLog 2 "test: %i" 42 // prints 'test: 42'
debugLog 4 "test: %i" 42 // prints nothing
```

Comment: I liked both answers a lot, but the one below seems a bit more idiomatic. In any case, really thanks!