# Combining functions with the same, but partially unknown signature

Tags: f#

Suppose we have a number of filter functions that accept the same parameters and return a boolean result.

```
let filter1 _ _ = true
let filter2 _ _ = false
```

These can be combined into a single filter.

```
let combine2 f1 f2 = fun a b -> f1 a b && f2 a b
combine2 filter1 filter2
```

Our implementation requires some knowledge of the parameters of `f1` and `f2`. More generally, we may find functions `combine1` ... `combineN` useful, where `N` is the number of parameters to the filter functions. Can a generic `combine` function be written that is independent of `N`?

I am interested in the capabilities of F# and being able to apply this concept in other situations.

**Update:** My understanding of the problem is that functions succeed in ignoring any remaining parameters when they don't care whether the result is a simple type or a partially applied function. In the example above, we only reach a boolean type after applying all parameters, so they need to be specified.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that such a generic combine could not be writeen whilst ensuring type safety

Comment: Well, there's the `printf` function, which uses a bit of magic to do things. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5572812/612512) may be useful.

Comment: @christopher from what I have read ([here](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/abusing-printfformat-in-f.html)), the implementation of `printf` is supported by the compiler rather than just using f# and .net constructs. The link you provide builds on this functionality and I don't see how to apply it in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use high order function, passing the function as argument

```
let combineN invoke filters = filters |> List.map invoke |> List.reduce (&&)
```

and use it like this

```
[filter1; filter2] |> combineN (fun f -> f 1 2) |> printfn "%b"
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EHC5di

you can also pass List.reduce parameter as argument, like `combineN (&&) (fun f -> f 1 2)`
but usually is easier to write List.map |> List.reduce

you can also use it with more arguments

```
let filter3 _ _ _ = true
let filter4 _ _ _ = true

[filter3; filter4] |> List.map (fun f -> f 1 2 3) |> List.reduce (&&) |> printfn "%b"
[filter3; filter4] |> combineN (fun f -> f 1 2 3) |> printfn "%b"
```

compiler will check types (number arguments)

```
//call list of function with 2 argument, with more arguments doesnt compile 
[filter1; filter2] |> combineN (fun f -> f 1 2 3) |> printfn "%b"
//mix functions with different arguments, doesnt compile either 
[filter1; filter3] |> combineN (fun f -> f 1 2 3) |> printfn "%b"
```

see demo

Comment: I think the idea is that there are N arguments, not N functions

Comment: use can use with it with more arguments ``[filter3; filter4] |> combineN (fun f -> f 1 2 3)`` . is type checked, see demo

Comment: I like this answer because it naturally extends the example to combine more than two filters. There is still a dependency on `N` to achieve the result of a combined filter function `fun a b -> [filter1; filter2] |> combineN (fun f -> f a b)`, but any complexity in the combine process is abstracted. As @john suggests, a dependency on `N` with this design is probably unavoidable.

Comment: you need only combineN function, no need to wrap in another function. 
Anyway the combineN is a bit useless, just do List.map |> List.reduce directly

Comment: I have two reasons for producing a function result. 1) It can be used independently or combined with additional filters. 2) The filter is passed to another function (like `List.filter`) that supplies the parameters. Retaining a `combineN` function is beneficial because it can be optimised to use short-circuit evaluation.