# How can I wrap sprintf + a call into a single function, and have two signatures, in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a function that takes a string and sends it to a terminal:

```
Print: string -> unit
```

it is passed to several modules that do this, to simplify the syntax

```
// printing
let print = settings.Print
```

and then it's used like that:

```
print "hello"
print (sprintf "the time is %A" DateTime.UtcNow)
```

my question is: Can I make two functions, with the same name but two signatures, so I could use it to either print a string, or a sprintf, then print the string.
for example:

```
print "hello"
print "the time is %A" DateTime.UtcNow
```

Is this possible? the goal is to simplify the syntax as a lot of code is peppered with info being sent to the terminal (which is currently a Telegram channel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kprintf` for this:

```
let myPrint s = printfn "My print: %s !" s

let print x = Printf.kprintf myPrint x
    
print "%d" 1
print "aaaa"
print "%s %s" "b" "c"
```

There are some examples [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/#the-kprintf-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570101/12463032).

I couldn't find `kprintf` documentation, so I'm not sure that this usage is correct, but it produces the correct result for me. Another possible candidate is `ksprintf`, which also produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same signature as sprintf:

```
let print (format : Printf.StringFormat<'T>) =
    sprintf format
    |> dosomethingElse
```

and you can use it as you want:

```
print "hello"
print "the time is %A" DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: This does not work, because the `print` function needs to propagate all extra parameters to `sprintf` - `kprintf` makes that possible by moving `dosomethingElse` into a continuation passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @TomasPetricek you're right, when I tested it compiled when up to right before the pipeline and both returned strings as I expected.