# Is it possible to create a custom Printf.TextWriterFormat?

Tags: f#

I want to create a custom type in F# by analogy with `Printf.TextWriterFormat` (adding my `%.` parameters).
Is it possible?

P.S. I found only [how to create custom *Type provider*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/creating-a-type-provider)

*Edit*:
I want to add new qualifiers with generation static types. Or creating my format string with generation static types. I don't want to use standard `Printf.TextWriterFormat` or combination with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf style logging for f#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277902/printf-style-logging-for-f)

Comment: If you want to use printf-style string formatting in your functions, and then apply some custom logic to the generated strings, see the linked question.

Comment: @scrwtp I want to add new qualifiers with generation static types. Or creating my format string with generation static types.

Comment: @FoggyFinder For example, I want to write: 'printfn "%w" MyRequest' (Or 'MyCustomPrintFunction "%w" MyRequest'). And compiler checks that MyRequest have type WebRequest.

Comment: May you explain why you need this?

Comment: @FoggyFinder For formatting built-in(.net, third-part) types (or my types without overriding 'ToString()'). Of course, I may creating special function " targetType -> string" and format any type :)

Comment: @EvgeniyMironov yep, my first thought was the option that you suggested second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot create arbitrary format literals. The closest you can get is to use the rather obscure `"%a"` [format specificier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-%5Bfsharp%5D), which is type-safe and could be just what you ask for:

```
open System
open System.IO


type MyRecord = {
    Name  : String
    Value : Int32
}


let myRecord = {
    Name  = "Hello World"
    Value = 42
}


let formatAsString () { Name = name; Value = value } =
    sprintf "RECORD NAME \"%s\" AND VALUE \"%d\"!" name value


let formatIntoWriter (writer : TextWriter) =
    formatAsString () >> writer.Write


// Functions from the Core.Printf module that return strings
// require a format function that returns a string.
let formattedAsString = sprintf "%a" formatAsString myRecord

// Functions from the Core.Printf module that return Unit
// require a format function that accepts a TextWriter.
printfn "%a" formatIntoWriter myRecord
```

The ugly thing is that depending on which format function you use (in the code I use `sprintf` and `printfn`), you have to provide a different formatting function for your custom type.

The good news is that this:

```
let printMyRecord = printfn "%a" formatIntoWriter
```

now has the type `MyRecord -> Unit`, so you can only pass instances of `MyRecord` to it.